# Set default window in Vim for opening all files/buffers

Tags: vim

Is it possible in Vim to set a default window for opening all files and buffers there?

Consider the following scenario:

I'm using Netrw and I'm positioned into the window that has the file list. Then I use :buffer or the wildmenu to open a file and it opens right there. I want the file to be opened in a default window, no matter where I'm positioned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for but you can use the `:Lexplore` command. It opens netrw in a vertical split in the current directory (`:pwd`). You can then open a file in the other vertical split. I haven't used it much, so I don't know it's exact behavior when you have multiple splits. You can open an additional a vertical split by using `v` in the netrw buffer.

I have the following mapping which opens netrw in a small vertical split:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>le :Lexplore<bar>vertical resize 30<CR>
```